# how to create Duval Triangle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, opengl-es

I need to create a triangle which called a duval triangle. It looks like this:
[image]

I need to do it with canvas. so far I succeed to create a triangle. But I don't know how to color it up and how to divide the area inside the triangle into a different colors like in the picture.
Can I do such thing in canvas, is it possible to create duval triangle in canvas.
Any help is blessed :).
The code so far:

```js
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");
var ctx = triangle.getContext("2d");
var cw = triangle.width = 500;
var ch = triangle.height = 500;

function createIntervalA(){
  ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(250,0);
  ctx.lineTo(0,250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.stroke();
  
}

createIntervalA();

function CreateIntervalB() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,250);
  ctx.lineTo(500,250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.stroke();
}
CreateIntervalB();

function CreateIntervalC() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(250,0);
  ctx.lineTo(500,250);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.stroke();
}
CreateIntervalC();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#triangle {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="triangle"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am going to give bounty for this question

Comment: You can certainly do this in html5 canvas using basic drawing context commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

*Disclaimer: I don't have a background in Chemical Engineering -- so bear with me. :-)*

I googled [this description](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4345236_A_Software_Implementation_of_the_Duval_Triangle_Method) of implementing a Duval Triangles, but I found the paper beyond my knowledge of Electro-Chemistry. So as a workaround I built snippets to help you draw your Duval Triangle since you already have the required knowledge.

**Drawing the segments inside the Duval Triangle (D1,D2,DT,PD,T1,T2,T3)**

Assume you define your triangle segments in objects like this:

```
// the definition of the D2 segment
{
    // The vertices that outline the D2 segment 
    points:[{x:385,y:366},{x:201,y:366},{x:324,y:150},{x:356,y:204},{x:321,y:256}],
    // The fill color of the D2 segment
    fill:'deepskyblue',
    // The label for the D2 segment
    // By default, the label is inside the segment, 
    //    but can be outside with a connecting line
    label:{text:'D2',cx:290,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
},
```

You can draw the segment using that segment-object definition using the `drawSegment` function. See the example code at the bottom of this post.

[image]

**Drawing the triangle outline and the percentage tickmarks (20,40,60,80)**

Assume you define your total triangle like this:

```
// define the 3 vertices of the triangle
var v0={x:114,y:366};
var v1={x:306,y:30};
var v2={x:498,y:366};
var triangle=[v0,v1,v2];
```

You can draw the triangle using the `drawTriangle` function and draw the tick marks using the `ticklines` function in the example code.

[image]

**Drawing the molecule labels**

The same triangle definition is used to draw the molecule labels (and arrows) outside the triangle using the `moleculeLabel` function in the example code.

[image]

**Drawing the chart legend**

Assuming you define the text of the chart legend like this:

```
var legendTexts=[
    'PD = Partial Discharge',
    'T1 = Thermal fault < 300 celcius',
    '...'
];
```

You can draw the chart legend using the `drawLegend` function in the example code.

[image]

**Putting it all together in an example:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4345236_A_Software_Implementation_of_the_Duval_Triangle_Method

var v0={x:114,y:366};
var v1={x:306,y:30};
var v2={x:498,y:366};
var triangle=[v0,v1,v2];

// Define all your segments here
var segments=[
  { 
    points:[{x:114,y:366},{x:281,y:76},{x:324,y:150},{x:201,y:366}],
    fill:'rgb(172,236,222)',
    label:{text:'D1',cx:200,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:385,y:366},{x:201,y:366},{x:324,y:150},{x:356,y:204},{x:321,y:256}],
    fill:'deepskyblue',
    label:{text:'D2',cx:290,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:297,y:46},{x:392,y:214},{x:372,y:248},{x:441,y:366},{x:385,y:366},{x:321,y:256},{x:356,y:204},{x:281,y:76}],
    fill:'lightCyan',
    label:{text:'DT',cx:370,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:366,endY:120},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:306,y:30},{x:312,y:40},{x:300,y:40}],
    fill:'black',
    label:{text:'PD',cx:356,cy:40,withLine:true,endX:321,endY:40},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:312,y:40},{x:348,y:103},{x:337,y:115},{x:297,y:46},{x:300,y:40}],
    fill:'navajoWhite',
    label:{text:'T1',cx:375,cy:70,withLine:true,endX:340,endY:75},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:348,y:103},{x:402,y:199},{x:392,y:214},{x:337,y:115}],
    fill:'tan',
    label:{text:'T2',cx:400,cy:125,withLine:true,endX:366,endY:120},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:402,y:199},{x:498,y:366},{x:441,y:366},{x:372,y:248}],
    fill:'peru',
    label:{text:'T3',cx:425,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
];

  // label styles
  var labelfontsize=12;
  var labelfontface='verdana';
  var labelpadding=3;

  // pre-create a canvas-image of the arrowhead
  var arrowheadLength=10;
  var arrowheadWidth=8;
  var arrowhead=document.createElement('canvas');
  premakeArrowhead();

  var legendTexts=['PD = Partial Discharge','T1 = Thermal fault < 300 celcius','...'];


// start drawing
/////////////////////


// draw colored segments inside triangle
for(var i=0;i<segments.length;i++){
  drawSegment(segments[i]);
}
// draw ticklines
ticklines(v0,v1,9,0,20);
ticklines(v1,v2,9,Math.PI*3/4,20);
ticklines(v2,v0,9,Math.PI*5/4,20);
// molecules
moleculeLabel(v0,v1,100,Math.PI,'% CH4');
moleculeLabel(v1,v2,100,0,'% C2H4');
moleculeLabel(v2,v0,75,Math.PI/2,'% C2H2');
// draw outer triangle
drawTriangle(triangle);
// draw legend
drawLegend(legendTexts,10,10,12.86);

// end drawing
/////////////////////

function drawSegment(s){
  // draw and fill the segment path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x,s.points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<s.points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(s.points[i].x,s.points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=s.fill;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.stroke();
  // draw segment's box label
  if(s.label.withLine){
    lineBoxedLabel(s,labelfontsize,labelfontface,labelpadding);
  }else{
    boxedLabel(s,labelfontsize,labelfontface,labelpadding);
  }
}


function moleculeLabel(start,end,offsetLength,angle,text){
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font='14px verdana';
  var dx=end.x-start.x;
  var dy=end.y-start.y;
  var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.50);
  var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.50);
  var x1=parseInt(x0+offsetLength*Math.cos(angle));
  var y1=parseInt(y0+offsetLength*Math.sin(angle));
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,x1,y1);
  // arrow
  var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.35);
  var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.35);
  var x1=parseInt(x0+50*Math.cos(angle));
  var y1=parseInt(y0+50*Math.sin(angle));
  var x2=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.65);
  var y2=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.65);
  var x3=parseInt(x2+50*Math.cos(angle));
  var y3=parseInt(y2+50*Math.sin(angle));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.stroke();
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  ctx.translate(x3,y3);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(arrowhead,-arrowheadLength,-arrowheadWidth/2);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}


function boxedLabel(s,fontsize,fontface,padding){
  var centerX=s.label.cx;
  var centerY=s.label.cy;
  var text=s.label.text;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface
  var textwidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
  var textheight=fontsize*1.286;
  var leftX=centerX-textwidth/2-padding;
  var topY=centerY-textheight/2-padding;
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY);
}


function lineBoxedLabel(s,fontsize,fontface,padding){
  var centerX=s.label.cx;
  var centerY=s.label.cy;
  var text=s.label.text;
  var lineToX=s.label.endX;
  var lineToY=s.label.endY;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface
  var textwidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
  var textheight=fontsize*1.286;
  var leftX=centerX-textwidth/2-padding;
  var topY=centerY-textheight/2-padding;
  // the line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(leftX,topY+textheight/2);
  ctx.lineTo(lineToX,topY+textheight/2);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.stroke();
  // the boxed text
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.strokeRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY);
}


function ticklines(start,end,count,angle,length){
  var dx=end.x-start.x;
  var dy=end.y-start.y;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  for(var i=1;i<count;i++){
    var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*i/count);
    var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*i/count);
    var x1=parseInt(x0+length*Math.cos(angle));
    var y1=parseInt(y0+length*Math.sin(angle));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(i==2 || i==4 || i==6 || i==8){
      var labelOffset=length*3/4;
      var x1=parseInt(x0-labelOffset*Math.cos(angle));
      var y1=parseInt(y0-labelOffset*Math.sin(angle));
      ctx.fillStyle='black';
      ctx.fillText(parseInt(i*10),x1,y1);
    }
  }
}


function premakeArrowhead(){
  var actx=arrowhead.getContext('2d');
  arrowhead.width=arrowheadLength;
  arrowhead.height=arrowheadWidth;
  actx.beginPath();
  actx.moveTo(0,0);
  actx.lineTo(arrowheadLength,arrowheadWidth/2);
  actx.lineTo(0,arrowheadWidth);
  actx.closePath();
  actx.fillStyle='black';
  actx.fill();
}


function drawTriangle(t){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(t[0].x,t[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(t[1].x,t[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(t[2].x,t[2].y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.stroke();
}


function drawLegend(texts,x,y,lineheight){
  ctx.textAlign='left';
  ctx.textBaseline='top';
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.font='12px arial';
  for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
    ctx.fillText(texts[i],x,y+i*lineheight);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: wow!! but why when I copy the code to another environment it doesn't work properly? Did you used any external library?

Comment: @Brk. Nope, just pure Javascript and html5 Canvas. Anything in your F12 console? What isn't working properly? Which other "environment"?

Comment: amazing, you are the best.

Comment: can you explain me, how you calculated the segments?

Comment: Hey markE, thx for the detailed answered. I need to build 2 more of these triangles and I would like to know , how you calculate the segments

Comment: You're welcome! My background only includes college chemistry & electronics classes from many (many!) years ago so I can't help with the calculations. I googled [this set of calculations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4345236_A_Software_Implementation_of_the_Duval_Triangle_Method), which I assume you have the knowledge to decipher since you asked the question. :-)

Comment: I don't have such knowledge, I am a programmer just like you.
Any way I still don't understand how you got the segment point according to current article. Can you be more specific and demonstrate at least one calculation of one segment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Brk. Nope. As I said in my answer, I found, but I don't have knowledge of, the information in that article. I suspect if you don't have the knowledge either, you will have to ask somewhere other than Stackoverflow because that knowledge is more scientific rather than programmatic. Good luck with your project!

Comment: I am talking about these points:
 points:[{x:114,y:366},{x:281,y:76},{x:324,y:150},{x:201,y:366}]
from where did you got them,from the essay because I don't see them there.

Comment: Understood. Those points are from your image ... not from an electro-chemical calculation. Again, I don't have the expertise to help you plot the points in an electro-chemical chart (and I doubt you'll find that expertise on Stackoverflow). I just provided the code necessary to display the chart once you have plotted your points.

Comment: from my image, but no coordinates on my image, only precntages of gases around the triangle. can you be more specific, I am willing to open a new discussion for this. I am really need this explanation , I need to calculate more 2 triangles and I need to know the process.

Comment: I opened up Photoshop and used the mouse to get the [x,y] vectors of each polygon. Then I fed those vectors into points[].  Again, AGAIN(!), I don't have knowledge of electro-chemistry so I can't help you with electro-chemical calculations.

Comment: Dude. You are a legend. Thank you for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The final answer(all credits to @markE for his greater efforts)

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4345236_A_Software_Implementation_of_the_Duval_Triangle_Method

var v0={x:114,y:366};
var v1={x:306,y:30};
var v2={x:498,y:366};
var triangle=[v0,v1,v2];

// Define all your segments here
var segments=[
  { 
    points:[{x:114,y:366},{x:281,y:76},{x:324,y:150},{x:201,y:366}],
    fill:'rgb(172,236,222)',
    label:{text:'D1',cx:200,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:385,y:366},{x:201,y:366},{x:324,y:150},{x:356,y:204},{x:321,y:256}],
    fill:'deepskyblue',
    label:{text:'D2',cx:290,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:297,y:46},{x:392,y:214},{x:372,y:248},{x:441,y:366},{x:385,y:366},{x:321,y:256},{x:356,y:204},{x:281,y:76}],
    fill:'lightCyan',
    label:{text:'DT',cx:370,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:366,endY:120},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:306,y:30},{x:312,y:40},{x:300,y:40}],
    fill:'black',
    label:{text:'PD',cx:356,cy:40,withLine:true,endX:321,endY:40},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:312,y:40},{x:348,y:103},{x:337,y:115},{x:297,y:46},{x:300,y:40}],
    fill:'navajoWhite',
    label:{text:'T1',cx:375,cy:70,withLine:true,endX:340,endY:75},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:348,y:103},{x:402,y:199},{x:392,y:214},{x:337,y:115}],
    fill:'tan',
    label:{text:'T2',cx:400,cy:125,withLine:true,endX:366,endY:120},
  },
  { 
    points:[{x:402,y:199},{x:498,y:366},{x:441,y:366},{x:372,y:248}],
    fill:'peru',
    label:{text:'T3',cx:425,cy:290,withLine:false,endX:null,endY:null},
  },
];

  // label styles
  var labelfontsize=12;
  var labelfontface='verdana';
  var labelpadding=3;

  // pre-create a canvas-image of the arrowhead
  var arrowheadLength=10;
  var arrowheadWidth=8;
  var arrowhead=document.createElement('canvas');
  premakeArrowhead();

  var legendTexts=['PD = Partial Discharge','T1 = Thermal fault < 300 celcius','...'];


// start drawing
/////////////////////


// draw colored segments inside triangle
for(var i=0;i<segments.length;i++){
  drawSegment(segments[i]);
}
// draw ticklines
ticklines(v0,v1,9,0,20);
ticklines(v1,v2,9,Math.PI*3/4,20);
ticklines(v2,v0,9,Math.PI*5/4,20);
// molecules
moleculeLabel(v0,v1,100,Math.PI,'% CH4');
moleculeLabel(v1,v2,100,0,'% C2H4');
moleculeLabel(v2,v0,75,Math.PI/2,'% C2H2');
// draw outer triangle
drawTriangle(triangle);
// draw legend
drawLegend(legendTexts,10,10,12.86);

// end drawing
/////////////////////

function drawSegment(s){
  // draw and fill the segment path
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(s.points[0].x,s.points[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<s.points.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(s.points[i].x,s.points[i].y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=s.fill;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.stroke();
  // draw segment's box label
  if(s.label.withLine){
    lineBoxedLabel(s,labelfontsize,labelfontface,labelpadding);
  }else{
    boxedLabel(s,labelfontsize,labelfontface,labelpadding);
  }
}


function moleculeLabel(start,end,offsetLength,angle,text){
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font='14px verdana';
  var dx=end.x-start.x;
  var dy=end.y-start.y;
  var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.50);
  var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.50);
  var x1=parseInt(x0+offsetLength*Math.cos(angle));
  var y1=parseInt(y0+offsetLength*Math.sin(angle));
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,x1,y1);
  // arrow
  var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.35);
  var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.35);
  var x1=parseInt(x0+50*Math.cos(angle));
  var y1=parseInt(y0+50*Math.sin(angle));
  var x2=parseInt(start.x+dx*0.65);
  var y2=parseInt(start.y+dy*0.65);
  var x3=parseInt(x2+50*Math.cos(angle));
  var y3=parseInt(y2+50*Math.sin(angle));
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
  ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.stroke();
  var angle=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
  ctx.translate(x3,y3);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(arrowhead,-arrowheadLength,-arrowheadWidth/2);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}


function boxedLabel(s,fontsize,fontface,padding){
  var centerX=s.label.cx;
  var centerY=s.label.cy;
  var text=s.label.text;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface
  var textwidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
  var textheight=fontsize*1.286;
  var leftX=centerX-textwidth/2-padding;
  var topY=centerY-textheight/2-padding;
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.strokeRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY);
}


function lineBoxedLabel(s,fontsize,fontface,padding){
  var centerX=s.label.cx;
  var centerY=s.label.cy;
  var text=s.label.text;
  var lineToX=s.label.endX;
  var lineToY=s.label.endY;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle'
  ctx.font=fontsize+'px '+fontface
  var textwidth=ctx.measureText(text).width;
  var textheight=fontsize*1.286;
  var leftX=centerX-textwidth/2-padding;
  var topY=centerY-textheight/2-padding;
  // the line
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(leftX,topY+textheight/2);
  ctx.lineTo(lineToX,topY+textheight/2);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  ctx.stroke();
  // the boxed text
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.fillRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.strokeRect(leftX,topY,textwidth+padding*2,textheight+padding*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillText(text,centerX,centerY);
}


function ticklines(start,end,count,angle,length){
  var dx=end.x-start.x;
  var dy=end.y-start.y;
  ctx.lineWidth=1;
  for(var i=1;i<count;i++){
    var x0=parseInt(start.x+dx*i/count);
    var y0=parseInt(start.y+dy*i/count);
    var x1=parseInt(x0+length*Math.cos(angle));
    var y1=parseInt(y0+length*Math.sin(angle));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    if(i==2 || i==4 || i==6 || i==8){
      var labelOffset=length*3/4;
      var x1=parseInt(x0-labelOffset*Math.cos(angle));
      var y1=parseInt(y0-labelOffset*Math.sin(angle));
      ctx.fillStyle='black';
      ctx.fillText(parseInt(i*10),x1,y1);
    }
  }
}


function premakeArrowhead(){
  var actx=arrowhead.getContext('2d');
  arrowhead.width=arrowheadLength;
  arrowhead.height=arrowheadWidth;
  actx.beginPath();
  actx.moveTo(0,0);
  actx.lineTo(arrowheadLength,arrowheadWidth/2);
  actx.lineTo(0,arrowheadWidth);
  actx.closePath();
  actx.fillStyle='black';
  actx.fill();
}


function drawTriangle(t){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(t[0].x,t[0].y);
  ctx.lineTo(t[1].x,t[1].y);
  ctx.lineTo(t[2].x,t[2].y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.stroke();
}


function drawLegend(texts,x,y,lineheight){
  ctx.textAlign='left';
  ctx.textBaseline='top';
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.font='12px arial';
  for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
    ctx.fillText(texts[i],x,y+i*lineheight);
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=650 height=500></canvas>
```